# which icCube-data folders to backup

Tags: iccube

I'd like to know which are the iccube folder(s) in order to create a daily backup and save my precious setup.
Should I save the entire icCube-data folder ? Or may I be more selective with subfolders ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude the /log /tmp and /schemaData directories. Remember to backup (although not daily) the configuration and startup script if you've made some changes (e.g., icCube.xml, icCube.sh, etc...).

Hope that helps.